# Indentation standard for ML and/or SML?

Tags: indentation, sml

Is there an indentation standard for ML or SML? I've noticed that many number of spaces work. Is there a convention about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a standard.  The cite referred to by JCPedroza is the standards of the theorem proving group at TU Munich, not the SML world.  For example, [the MLton source](http://mlton.org/) uses 3 spaces.

Ocaml is not much different. The conventions of Jane Street's Core library differ from the OCaml compiler source to some extent.